# Tornadofx tableview with first row at the bottom of header as filter fields

Tags: filter, synchronization, tableview, tornadofx

I'm looking for a tornadofx tableview with the first row just at the bottom of the header used as filter fields. Data are stored from second row to plus.
But unfortunately, there is not such a uicomponent in tornodofx and neither in javafx.

I was thinking to build this component by using 2 tableviews A and B gathered in a vbox. A has a header and 1 row with filter fields and B has no header and is synced with the filter-fields from A.

**Problem is I'm facing some challenges:**

- hiding a tableview is not easy (some people use code and some use CSS, which method is the better one ?)
- syncing 2 tableviews (resizing column width, ordering ASC/DESC in A should happen in B)
- filter-fields in A could be Excel-like filters and depend on the data type of each column

Can you help please ?

Thks

Answer (score 0):

I used column header graphics to achieve the result you wanted. I have to say I'm happy with myself for figuring this out because it avoids all the complications you were planning on dealing with like excluding the first row from the search, synchronizing two tables, etc.

```
class Foo(y: Int, z: String) {
    val yProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(y)
    var y by yProperty
    val zProperty = SimpleStringProperty(z)
    var z by zProperty
}


class TestView : View("Hello TornadoFX") {
    val list = SortedFilteredList<Foo>().apply {
        for(i in 0..10) {
            add(Foo(Random.nextInt(0, 100), "Row $i"))
        }
    }
    var column1Field: TextField by singleAssign()
    var column2Field: TextField by singleAssign()

    override val root = vbox {
        tableview(list) {
            column("", Foo::yProperty) { //Put column name in graphic so text field will be below label
                graphic = vbox(2) {
                    label("Y Column")
                    column1Field = textfield()
                }
            }
            column("", Foo::zProperty) {
                graphic = vbox(2){
                    label("Z Column")
                    column2Field = textfield()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        column1Field.textProperty().onChange { filterList() }
        column2Field.textProperty().onChange { filterList() }
    }

    fun filterList() {
        list.predicate = { row ->
            val c1Text = column1Field.text
            val c1Filter = if(!c1Text.isNullOrBlank()) row.y.toString().contains(c1Text, true)
            else true

            val c2Text = column2Field.text
            val c2Filter = if(!c2Text.isNullOrBlank()) row.z.contains(c2Text, true)
            else true

            c1Filter && c2Filter
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a rough POC and could probably be streamlined but I think it gets the idea across. I'll admit that it's a bit verbose but if you were clever enough, you could probably make builder functions to shrink this process down.

Comment: Thks for the solution.
I tried it and I had to replace Random.nextInt(0, 100) by (1..100).shuffled().first() to make it compiled.
The result is very interesting.

Comment: Is this solution satisfactory?

Comment: After some deeper research, I found Tornadofx-Controlfx that has a filter like I was looking for: https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-controlsfx
Thks Edvin